# Userscript works in Chrome/Tampermoney but not in Firefox/Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox

The purpose of [this userscript](https://github.com/janosgyerik/userscripts/blob/075116ad3451e3c0f577bb31b21ed0942c12fd8b/se-moderator-flag-notification.user.js) is, when you visit the `/review` page of a Stack Exchange website, it adds a **Desktop Notifications** link near the top, and if you visit that page, it generates a desktop notification if there are moderator flags or posts to review. The script reloads itself periodically.

This works out of the box in any Chrome/Tampermonkey I tried in multiple OS-es (OSX, Linux, Windows). In Firefox/Greasemonkey it doesn't work in OSX (the **Desktop Notifications** doesn't appear). If I recall correctly, it does work in Linux. The **Web Developer Console** doesn't show anything when I visit the page. The userscript is of course installed and enabled.

What could I be missing? How to debug this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Moderator Flag Notification
// @author Simon Forsberg
// @description Shows a desktop notification when there are flags or review items to be handled.
// @namespace https://github.com/Zomis/SE-Scripts
// @grant GM_getValue
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_notification
// @match *://*.stackexchange.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackoverflow.com/review*
// @match *://*.superuser.com/review*
// @match *://*.serverfault.com/review*
// @match *://*.askubuntu.com/review*
// @match *://*.stackapps.com/review*
// @match *://*.mathoverflow.net/review*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.location.href.indexOf('/desktop-notifications') === -1) {
    $('.tools-rev h1').append('<span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/review/desktop-notifications">Desktop Notifications</a></h1>');
} else {
    var KEY_NEXT = 'NextReload';
    var DELAY = 60 * 1000;
    var currentTime = Date.now ? Date.now() : new Date().getTime();
    var lastTime = GM_getValue(KEY_NEXT, 0);
    var nextTime = currentTime + DELAY;
    GM_setValue(KEY_NEXT, nextTime);

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(lastTime - currentTime);
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, DELAY);

    $('.subheader h1').html('Desktop Notifications');
    $('.leftcol').html('Keep your browser open on this page and it will be automatically reloaded and alert you when something wants your attention.').removeClass('leftcol');
    $('.rightcol').remove();

    var title = document.title.split(' - '); // keep the site name
    document.title = 'Desktop Notifications - ' + title[1];

    // a way to detect that the script is being executed because of an automatic script reload, not by the user.
    if (timeDiff <= DELAY * 2) {
        var notifications = [];

        var topbarFlag = $('.topbar-links .mod-only .icon-flag .flag-count').html();
        var topbarFlagCount = parseInt(topbarFlag);
        if (topbarFlagCount > 0) {
            notifications.push(topbarFlagCount + ' Flags');
        }

        var reviewItems = $('.icon-tools-flag span');
        var reviewCount = 0;
        if (reviewItems.length > 0) {
            reviewCount = parseInt(reviewItems.html());
            if (reviewCount > 0) {
                notifications.push(reviewCount + ' Review Items');
            }
        }

        if (notifications.length > 0) {
            var details = {
                title: document.title,
                text: notifications.join('\n'),
                timeout: 0
            };
            GM_notification(details, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [GreaseMonkey's source](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/master/modules/util/sniffGrants.js#L5), the `GM_notification` API is not implemented yet.

Issue [#1194](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1194) is the relavent issue. (I don't think that it will be added anytime soon)

As a temporary polyfill, you can have at the start of the file:

```
if (!GM_notification) {
    GM_notification = function(details) {
        alert(details.title + '\n' + details.text);
    }
}
```

This makes the tab look like:

[image: Tab title font is bold and favicon has flash]

But won't produce a notification. You should also have information in the `document.title` now, as there won't be any actual notifications (Like the number of notifications in square brackets).

There isn't much else you could do that won't just be an inconvenience when users were doing other things, like `window.open` to steal focus (But most attempts will probably be blocked) to a newly opened tab.

A long term solution to this is to make this into an extension, as both Firefox and Chrome extensions support notifications.

Comment: If an undefined `GM_notification` was the issue, the script would crash only when that line is executed, no? At the moment the script is not working at all. It does not add the **Desktop Notifications** link, for example.

Comment: It seems I have a more fundamental issue... If I replace the entire script (below the header) with a single line `document.title = 'hello';`, even that doesn't work. So I guess I installed the script incorrectly somehow. On the GitHub page I linked, when I click on the `[Raw]` button Greasemonkey offers to install it. That's how I installed it. And when I visit a review page, the Greasemonkey menu indicates that the script it is active. What could I be missing?

Comment: @janos Go to `about:addons` in Firefox, and you should see a User Scripts tab on the left bar. From there, check if the script is installed, then check if it's enabled, then go to Options->Edit this userscript. From there, check if it installed the right script.

Comment: The User Scripts tab is there. The script is listed and enabled. Instead of Options, I guess you meant Preferences. That's how I edited the script as I mentioned in my previous comment. After my edit, I tried to disable and re-enable, in case that helps, but it doesn't. I tried simple commands like the `document.title = '...'` I mentioned, or `console.log('hello')`. But none of these get executed, so it seems the script is not running at all.